# Elegant linq solution for left joins with unique data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, left-join, unique

I woud like to inquire if my Linq solution below is a good solution or if there is a better way. I am new to using Linq, and am most familiar with MySQL. So I've been converting one of my past projects from PHP to .NET MVC and am trying to learn Linq. I would like to find out if there is a better solution than the one I came up with.

I have the following table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE maplocations (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    Lat double NOT NULL,
    Lng double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY name (name)
);

CREATE TABLE reservations (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    loc_ID INT NOT NULL,
    resDate DATE NOT NULL,
    user_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY one_per (loc_ID, resDate),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_ID) REFERENCES Users (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (loc_ID) REFERENCES MapLocations (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    salt VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_names (name),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_email (email)
);
```

In MySQL, I use the following query to get the ealiest reservation at each maplocation with a non null date for any locations that don't have a reservation.

```
SELECT locs.*, if(res.resDate,res.resDate,'0001-01-01') as resDate, res.Name as User
FROM MapLocations locs
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT loc_ID, resDate, Name 
    FROM Reservations, Users
    WHERE resDate >= Date(Now())
    AND user_ID = Users.ID
    ORDER BY resDate
) res on locs.ID = res.loc_ID
group by locs.ID
ORDER BY locs.Name;
```

In Linq, with Visual studio automatically creating much of the structure after connecting to the database, I have come up with the following equivalent to that SQL Query

```
var resList = (from res in Reservations
    where res.ResDate >= DateTime.Today
    select res);

var locAndRes = 
    (from loc in Maplocations 
    join res in resList on loc.ID equals res.Loc_ID into join1
    from res2 in join1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join usr in Users on res2.User_ID equals usr.ID into join2
    from usr2 in join2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby loc.ID,res2.ResDate
    select new {
            ID = (int)loc.ID,
            Name = (string)loc.Name,
            Lat = (double)loc.Lat,
            Lng = (double)loc.Lng,
            resDate = res2 != null ?(DateTime)res2.ResDate : DateTime.MinValue,
            user = usr2 != null ? usr2.Name : null
    }).GroupBy(a => a.ID).Select(b => b.FirstOrDefault());
```

So, I'm wondering is there a better way to perform this query?
Are these equivalent?
Are there any good practices I should be following?

Also, one more question, I'm having trouble getting this from the `var` to a List. doing something like this doesn't work

```
List<locAndResModel> locList = locAndRes.AsQueryable().ToList<locAndResModel>();
```

In the above snippet `locAndResModel` is just a class which has variables to match the int, string, double double, DateTime, string results of the query. Is there an easy way to get a list without having to do a foreach and passing the results to a constructor override? Or should I just add it to ViewData and return the View?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so and you have foreign keys, some of the joining is already done for you. Also, You cannot coerce an anonymous type to a declared type with ToList. You'll have to use a new instance of that type in your select.

Comment: @James Thank you for the response. Yes it's using Entity framework. I'm rather new to that as well. I never though to use locAndResModel inside the select. So it seems this should work in the last query: `select new locAndResModel( (int)loc.ID, (string)loc.name, (double)loc.Lat, (double)loc.Lng, res2 != null ? (DateTime)res2.resDate : DateTime.MinValue, (string)usr2.name )`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take advantage of the automatic joins performed by the Entity Framework. Give this a try and let me know if it does what you want:

```
var locAndRes = from maplocation in MapLocations
                let earliestReservationDate = maplocation.Reservations.Min(res => res.resDate) 
                let earliestReservation = (from reservation in mapLocation.Reservations
                                           where reservation.resDate == earliestReservationDate && reservation.resDate >= DateTime.Today
                                           select reservation).FirstOrDefault()
                select new locAndResModel( maplocation.ID, maplocation.name, maplocation.Lat, maplocation.Lng, earliestReservation != null ? earliestReservation.resDate : DateTime.MinValue, earliestReservation != null ?earliestReservation.User.name : null)
```

Comment: Everything seems good except that I get "Specified method is not supported" coming from MySQL.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit

Comment: @Gamil Sorry realized I typoed and left the parens off of FirstOrDefault. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Nope. I noticed that when I was putting it into VS. And again, thank you for your help. I've done a bit of digging, it seems to be something with MySQL and Entity Framework. I've seen a couple posts about the problem, and often it will work fine with MSSQL but not MySQL. So I'll try it in MSSQL (for academic purposes) and let you know how that goes.

Comment: You might also want to give http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ a look. Perhaps this provider for MySQL will play nicer.